# How to extract feature for an image after neural network training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

Is there a way to learn unsupervised features from set of images. Similar to `word2vec` or `doc2vec`, where neural network is learnt and given new document we get its features.

Expecting similar to this [example](https://dato.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/food_retrieval-public.html) shows that it can load learnt nn-model and predict features for new images.

Is there any simple example how to implement cnn over images and get their features back will help !!

Suppose in this [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)
If I want to get cnn features for all `X_train` and `X_test` ... is there any way?
Also, if we can get weights per layer per image, we can stack them and use as features. In that case is there a way to get the same.
Using those features for unsupervised task would be easier, if we consider them as vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, this task is quite common in a deep learning field. In case of images what I consider the best is a convolutional autoencoder. You may read about this architecture e.g. here

http://people.idsia.ch/~ciresan/data/icann2011.pdf

Previous version of Keras supported this architecture as one of core layers, though from version 1.0 I noticed that it disappeared from documentation. But - it's still quite easy to build it from a scratch :)

In noimage cases there are also another approaches like e.g. Restricted Boltzmann Machines.

UPDATE :

When it comes to what sort of activations are the best for obtaining new features from neural network activations - from my personal experience - it depends on the size of the net which you use. If you use a network which last layer is wide (has a lot of nodes) it might be useful to get only last layer (due to number of parameters if you want to consider also previous layers - it may harm the performance of learning). But - if (like in case of some MNIST networks) your last layer is not sufficient for this task - you may try using also previous layers activation or even all net activity. To be honest - I'm not expecting much of improvement in this case - but you may try. I think that you should use both approaches - starting from taking only last layer activations - and then trying to check the behaviour of your new classifier when you add activations from previous layers.

What I will strongly advise to you is also getting some insights from what sort of features network is learning - using T-SNE embeddings of it activations. In many cases I found it useful - e.g. checking if the size of a layer is sufficient. Using T-SNE you may check if the features obtained from last layer are good discriminators of your classes. It may also give you good insights about your data and what neural networks are really learning (alongside with amazing visualizations :) )

Comment: Thanks @Marcin .. I will look into the paper. What I wanted to understand was as in word2vec remove last layer and just take hidden layer weights as features ... For images does that still hold OR we have to take the weights from all layers ? And about keras v1.0 has major changes ... I don't see auto-encoder also !

Comment: Cool. Visualization is a good idea to understand the importance of features from particular layer. Thanks for the updated answer. I am moving from shallow network to deep network ... hence so many questions !! Thanks  again !!